# How to print the boot order of the `systemd` services?

Tags: systemd

How to print the boot order of the `systemd` services?

look like:

```
A.service
B.service
C.service
...
```

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29309717/is-there-any-way-to-list-systemd-services-in-linux-in-the-order-of-they-were-l

Comment: @marc it's good in SVG but I just want a list better with used time.

Comment: Are you looking for `# systemd-analyze blame` ?